# Transactional behavior across in-memory objects

Tags: .net-4.0, transactions

I want to make a sequence of in-memory operations atomic. I presume there is no framework supplied functionality for this and that I would have to implement my own rollback functionality using memento (or something)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it needs to be really atomic there is no such thing AFAIK in the Framework itself - [an interesting link discussing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461137/how-do-i-make-an-in-memory-process-transactional).

What you ask is called STM (Software Transactional Memory) and is an inherent part for example of Haskell.

Basically any implementation uses some sort of copy meachnism - either keeping the old data till the transaction is commited OR makring a copy first and then do all "changes" on the copy and switch references on commit... anyway always some log and/or copying mechanism involved...

For C# check these links out:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/6cfc842d-1c16-4739-afaf-edb35f544384/default.aspx
- http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/6/9560741A-EEFC-4C02-822C-BB0AFE860E31/STM_User_Guide.pdf
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stmteam/

IF F# is an option then check these links out:

- http://cs.hubfs.net/blogs/hell_is_other_languages/archive/2008/01/16/4565.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/Podwysocki/archive/2008/02/07/119387.aspx

Another option could be to use an "in-memory-Database" - there are several out there with transaction support thus providing atomic operation via the DB... as long as the DB is "in-memory" it should perform well